# How can I use the built in Object.assign in react?

Tags: reactjs

React used to have a merge util, that is now deprecated and replaced with https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dca7ffbe21d2b27d0c7ff898bbaa27dab84e4043/src/stubs/Object.assign.js

Just wonder if it's possible to use this version of assign in my code? Is it somehow possible to include it? If so, what path should I use?

thanks.

Comment: FWIW, [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html) currently seem to recommend using underscore/lodash instead: _"Underscore supports _.omit to filter out properties and _.extend to copy properties onto a new object."_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [object.assign package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign).  It is an ES6 Object.assign() "ponyfill".

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^0.12.0",
    ...
  },
```

Then where you want to use it:

```
var assign = require('object-assign');

var MessageStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

  emitChange: function() {
  ...
```

The [Facebook Flux Chat example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat) uses it.

Comment: You can also just use the es6 polyfill and get even more useful utilities.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) The repository owner explains ponyfill as a polyfill that doesn't overwrite the native method. I thought it was a common term :)

Comment: Heh, I haven't heard that one before.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `Object.assign` shipped with react 0.12 (`require('react/lib/Object.assign')`)

**WARNING**: this is private API which could change anytime so you can't really rely on it.

Comment: Any React helper deep in the package is considered a private API and is unsupported. It may be removed, moved or changed in the next version without notice.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to express concern about someone's use of a private API. However all the downvotes here are uncool. OP asked if it is "somehow possible to include" the React object.assign functionality. Not some other similar functionality, but that particular one. This poster answered the question perfectly, with clear detail. If you don't like the OP's question, offer your own alternate answer that clarifies a better option. But don't beat up on a poster who does as asked, and does so accurately.

Comment: @develop7 maybe you could edit your answer accordingly to the FWIW by XMLLilley above? You answered correctly, but it's not recommended to do it this way, but you should rather use lodash or underscore.